# Textview at the bottom of listview does not appear as listview adds more items?

Tags: android

In my first screen shot you can see expended listview at top and textview placed at below next to expended listview.
But if you look at my second screen shot, as the listview adds more items textview place at the bottom does not appear.

[image: screen 1]
[image: screen 2]

My layout code is :

```
<LinearLayout 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
android:id="@+id/form_view"  
>

  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
      <Spinner             
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
         android:layout_width="0dip"  
         android:layout_weight="2"                              
        android:id="@+id/spinnerSemester" />          

       <Button
            android:id="@+id/graph_button"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
           android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
            android:text="Chart" />
 </LinearLayout>

 <ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/lv_attendance"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    >
</ExpandableListView>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TV_note"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lv_attendance"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="[NOTE : The data displayed here is for advance information only. Please check with the college office/department concerned for the final and certified data. In case of discrepancies, the data maintained in the college records will be deemed to be the final one.]"
            android:layout_marginTop="10px"
            android:textSize="13sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks,
Nandakishore P

Comment: Your problem is that ExpandableListView has wrap_content for height so as it gets bigger it's going to push everything else down. You should use weighted heights I think.

Comment: yes i knew and i wanted to push it down but it should appear once i scroll down the listview.

Comment: Oh ok, then in that case you should try wrapping the entire layout in a scroll view.

Comment: @NandakishoreP...does any answer helped you to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try as below...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/form_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinnerSemester"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/graph_button"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:text="Chart" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_attendance"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" >
    </ExpandableListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TV_note"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="[NOTE : The data displayed here is for advance information only. Please check with the college office/department concerned for the final and certified data. In case of discrepancies, the data maintained in the college records will be deemed to be the final one.]"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

consider specifyig android:layout_weight to the views, also encasing that text view in a framelayout or linearlayout

Gods, I hate layout...

Answer (score 0):

Dont use android:layout_below="@+id/lv_attendance", its creating problem, use alignParentBottom instead.